# & 1 JavaScript. How does it work? Clever or good?

Tags: javascript, boolean, logic, operators

I'm looking over the solutions for a CodeWars problem (IQ Test) in which you're given a string of numbers and all the numbers but 1 are either even or odd. You need to return the index plus 1 of the position of the number that's not like the rest of the numbers.

I'm confused about the line that says & 1 in the solution posted below. The code doesn't work w/ && or w/ the & 1 taken away.

```
function iqTest(numbers){
  numbers = numbers.split(' ')

  var evens = []
  var odds = []

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] & 1) { //PLEASE EXPLAIN THIS LINE!
      odds.push(i + 1)
    } else {
      evens.push(i + 1)
    }
  }

  return evens.length === 1 ? evens[0] : odds[0]
}
```

Also, would you consider using & 1 to be best practice or is it just "clever" code?

Answer (score 2):

The single `&` is a ['bitwise' operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). This specific operator (`&`) is the bitwise AND operator - which returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of both operands are ones.

The way it's being used here is to test if `numbers[i]` is an even or odd number. As `i` loops from `0` to `numbers.length`, for the first iteration the `if` statement evaluates `0 & 1` which evaluates to `0`, or `false`. On the next iteration of the loop, the statement will be `1 & 1`, which evaluates to `1`, or `true`.

The result - when `numbers[i] & 1` evaluates to `0`, or `false`, then `numbers[i]` is pushed to the `odd` array. If `numbers[i] & 1` evaluates to `1`, or `true`, then `numbers[i]` is pushed to the `even` array.

An alternative to the `&` operator to test for even and odd is to use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder). `numbers[i] % 2` results in the same output. That is, `1 % 2` results in `1`, or `true` as will any odd number, because an odd number divided by 2 results in a remainder of 1. And any even number, like `2 % 2` results in `0` or `false` because an even number divided by 2 results in a remainder of 0.

As for your second question, is it 'clever or good?'. It's definitely clever. Whether it's good depends on who you ask and what your goal is. Many would say its less logical and harder to read than using `num % 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Binary number is `0` and `1` and each of them is called bit.

Single `&` is add operation and it works bitwise.

like

```
1 = 01
2 = 10 
3 = 11
4 = 100
```

You can see that every last bit of odd number is `1` and even number is `0`.

In add operation

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

So only odd number will return `1` and even number will return `0` and in programming only `0` consider `falsy`.

If we wanna to check `5` is a odd or even

```
5  = 101
```

and perform and(`&`) operation with `1`

```
  101 
& 001
-----
  001
```

and value of binary `001` is `1` in `10` base number

So it'll perform easy odd even process.